# How to leave apple developer program on developer.apple.com?

Tags: ios, developer-program

I have been a member of a few development teams, but no longer work with them. I would like to leave these organizations, as I use my current account at a new organization and don't want them to have access to the other one's developer program.

I was able to leave 2 organizations using the "leave team" button, however I cannot leave one - I click the leave team button, and the alert just refreshes and stays as is. Currently I have my personal developer program and that other organization available in the "teams" dropdown.

**Please help me understand how I can request to leave a team (I'm in the admin role for the team)**
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you click 'Leave Team' and the page refreshes but nothing changes?  Have you contacted Apple about that?

Comment: One resort that I know of is to request the Agent of the Team to revoke your access. If you can reach him/her, that would be the best resort. (IIRC, that was the only way to leave a team when I last checked).

Answer (score 20):

It's possible.

Goto:
[image]

Scroll down opened page and hit 'Leave':
[image]

Comment: I can't see the "Leave Team" option under there and also there is only "People" tab. No "Keys" tab :( don't know whats wrong here. I'm a part of an organization team.

Comment: @ChiragMS Hi. Did you select "Edit profile"? The whole path: "App Store Connect" -> "Users and Access" -> "Edit profile" -> "Action: Scroll down"

Comment: I solved it actually. I don't exactly know what fixed it but when I opened the page after sometime, It was there. Thanks much. Appreciate your help. 

Comment: The team I wanted to leave had the "App Store connect" button hidden. I was still able to go to AppStore connect through another team, and then removed myself from the first team. A bit of a workaround, but it worked.

Comment: here's the URL for the "App Store Connect": https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ Using this I was able to find the "leave" functionality

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the Apple support team they said they cannot remove me from the team because I have some kind of certificate issued and still active with that team.

Comment: all certificates linked to team will be recalled after leaving